# Word - delete text between <> including tables

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

I'm trying to delete text between < and > that includes 2 tables.  I can do text including multiple lines using wildcard search and replace using (\<)(*)(>)
but this doesn't work when the text includes tables.  Any ideas? There are varying numbers of lines in the tables too.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: I can't show a good example but it goes something like this:  <text line break formatted table line break formatted table line break text>

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2016/delete-text-between-including-tables/51f09dcb-8c77-41d3-840c-e8e0545f313a
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

The correct wildcard Find expression would be:

```
\<*\>
```

Nevertheless, your observation is correct: It won't find content that includes a table between the < and >. You would need to use two Find/Replace operations, one that uses the above expression then another that employs a loop, looking for

```
<
```

Then extending the found range until:

```
>
```

is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/delete-text-between-including-tables/51f09dcb-8c77-41d3-840c-e8e0545f313a?tm=1531844975462&auth=1

```
Dim rng As Range
 Selection.HomeKey wdStory
  With Selection.Find
      Do While .Execute(findText:="<", Forward:=True, _
      MatchWildcards:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop, MatchCase:=True) = True
          Set rng = Selection.Range
          rng.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
          rng.End = rng.Start + InStr(rng, ">")
          rng.Select
          Selection.Delete
      Loop
  End With
  End Sub
```